# Patience is a virtue. How long have users waited before getting responses to their comments?

Tags: support, statistics, data-explorer

So, I finally got a response to a comment asking "what version of sql server do you use?"..

..nearly [two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221100/grab-portions-of-a-string-when-the-string-has-dynamic-variables?noredirect=1#comment123089104_59221100)!

It set me thinking; I recall reading that SO has some sort of query language; could it be used to find out "who waited the longest/how long, to get a reply to a comment-on-question asking a question" and what would the query look like?

I suppose the criteria would be the max time between two comments where the first ended in a `?` and the second was the soonest comment that @'d the first (though in my case I wasn't @'d, so that could maybe be relaxed to first comment made by the OP after a comment ending in `?`)

Comment: I'm one of people Who ask or answer something few month or year after the question have been asked. And yes, it can be cool data to know how many year someone wait a reply xD

Comment: *"I recall reading that SO has some sort of query language;"* -  You're think of SEDE, it uses SQL, I'm sure one of the SEDE wizards out there could help out

Comment: The irony that the reply you got was *"I am using version 19"* A version that doesn't exist, at the time of this comment (and certainly didn't at the time of the question). I suspect it'll be *at least* a decade before we get the version the User is using.

Comment: You could write this in a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but I doubt it would be performant. Searching all the comments for those contain a `'?'` would not be SARGable, and with the limited resources you get on for the queries on SEDE, likely to timeout. This would probably need to be done in a local version, as it would most certainly be a long running query.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the pointer - I dare say I should now be able to work it out myself! (seems to be SQLServer syntax). I did have similar thoughts to Larnu - this is likely an horrific query but there may be some assumptions that could trim down the dataset, or it may be that querying it [on Google](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/), if it's still a thing, would have the performance grunt necessary for something awful like this

Comment: @Larnu yes, I laughed some at that one myself - especially as I've recently posted about the SSMS tagging, and all the versioning nonsense therein. It's like the universe is fractal and cycling back to poke fun at me

Comment: Impressed that it's letting me run 100s+ queries.. So far turned up this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373234 - 9 years waiting for a "yes"

Comment: S.Lott was waiting slightly longer for Paxdiablo to come back on [why their question mattered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386241) ..

Comment: What I find even more interesting is that there are two answers and at least 1 is upvoted. So, apparently those answerers didn't need to know the version to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @Braiam I think it's probably par for the course with the [sql] tag; definitely wild west territory where the fastest guns line up against Gordon and not much changes (in terms of DB capabilities) so you can quickly throw your "good for every SQLServer since 2000" string chop hat into the ring and stand a good chance of nailing some upvotes.. I asked specifically because I wanted to know if STRING_SPLIT was available but it's somewhat moot now, i think .. :)

Comment: @CaiusJard But any user with an old question can remove their comments on their question and re-reply a comment to create the illusion *(for fun, I suppose)*.

Comment: Perhaps one reasonable explanation.. If it's the case then it happens quite a lot. Interesting example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116533) (and the current leader in my querying) where kjagiello takes nearly 10 years to acknowledge a tagging observation. I wonder if mods can see whether there are any deleted comments.. There doesn't appear to be anything in the SEDE data that would allow me to infer it (such as a sequence number to comments), so I suppose it's down to finding a case where the conversation goes out of sync (a third party @'d the OP's response)

Comment: @CaiusJard Are you planning to make an answer with these provided as a list? It's a fun question

Comment: Well Caius, the other option is that you could say "if you have string_split do this, if you don't then do that". That's my strategy anyways.

Comment: @GammaGames I'm keeping track of the queries written, and tweaking them/having a play to see what I can identify and how far I can push it (already starting to hit a few timeouts). If it shapes up into something interesting I'll certainly make an answer

Answer (score 8):

14 Years ...

| avg hours waited | total comments > 1 hour | min hours waited | max hours waited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2,209 | 22,324,746 | 1 | 125,489 |

Based on [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1696805) where I assume that the next comment that this not from the same OP is a response. And for our own sanity I only took responses after one hour into account.

```
;with wait as (
select id [sid]
     , postid
     , lead(id) over (partition by postid order by creationdate) [nid]
from comments
)

select avg([hours]) [avg hours waited] 
     , count(*) [total comments > 1 hour] 
     , min([hours]) [min hours waited] 
     , max([hours]) [max hours waited] 
from(

select w.postid
     , datediff_big(hh, wc.creationdate, nc.creationdate) [hours]
from wait w
inner join comments wc on wc.id = w.sid
inner join comments nc 
   on nc.id = w.nid 
   and nc.postid = wc.postid
   and wc.userid <> nc.userid
where datediff_big(hh, wc.creationdate, nc.creationdate) > 0
   ) data
```

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: 2,209 hours is 92 days (3 months).